# How to empty input when change another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to empty the input value when another input value has changed.
I tried this code, but not working yet. Any idea to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="continer">
  <input type="text" class="type" id="type" value="">
  <input type="text" class="model" id="model" value="">
</div>

<script>
  $("#type").on('keydown', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
     if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
    $("#model").empty();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `change` event to trigger the change event and `.val()` method to set the value of the other inputs , like that

```
<script>
  $("#type").on('change', function() {
    $("#model").val("");
  });
</script>
```